# Unstaged file to recover

Tags: git

I did `git add`, `git commit -m "some msg"`, then I found that something is wrong in my `.gitignore`. Thus, I use `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. Suddenly, I lost all my previous files. Is there anyway that I can recover my files?  I tried to `git reset -- HEAD@{commit}` to where my last commit is, but it says that unstaged changes after reset. All those changes are my lost files but I can't find them in my directory. Is it possible for me to recover those files?

Comment: solved. My files are shown in "D" status, which means deleted. Just use "git checkout nameofFilesDeleted" to recover the files

Comment: then I found that something is wrong in my .gitignore. You should use `git commit --amend`.

Answer (score 0):

If the files you need to recover were committed, you can use `git reflog` to see what you have done recently and get back to a previous point in time.